# Why this code didn't work for -m32?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, 32bit-64bit

```
#include <stddef.h>

template<size_t N = sizeof(void*)> struct a;

template<> struct a<4> {
    enum { b };
};

template<> struct a<8> {
    template<int> struct b {};
};

enum { c, d };

int main() {
    a<>::b<c>d;
    d;
}
```

I have a piece of code which succesfully compiles for x64 architecture by gcc. But fails with `-m32` with error:

```
$ g++ -m32 test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:16:12: warning: comparison between ‘enum a<4u>::<anonymous>’ and ‘enum<anonymous>’ [-Wenum-compare]
     a<>::b<c>d;
            ^
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is correct. Clearly, since the warning is just a warning. It points towards the fact that the comparison involves two unrelated enumerations, so perhaps isn't sensible.

In case you're interested in an analysis:
Since you're compiling for x86-32, `sizeof(void*)` is 4. So `a<>` refers to `a<4>`, and subsequently `a<4>::b` refers to an enumerator.

So the expression-statement

```
a<>::b<c>d;
```

is parsed as

```
(a<>::b < c) > d;
```

Now the usual arithmetic conversions are performed, during which both operands are promoted to `int`, using the rules of integral promotion. [expr.rel]/2:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on operands of
>   arithmetic or enumeration type. […]. **After conversions, the operands shall have the same type.**

(Note the bold part, which is ensured later on.) [expr]/10:

> This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*,
>   which are defined as follows:
>
> - If either operand is of scoped enumeration type (7.2), no conversions are performed; if the other operand does not have the same
>     type, the expression is ill-formed.
> - [ …Bullet points concerning floating point types… ]
> - **Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands**. Then the following rules shall be applied to the
>     promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.
>   - […]

Integral promotion for enumerators is covered in [conv.prom]/3:

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not
>   fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the
>   following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration
>   (i.e., the values in the range *b<sub>min</sub>* to *b<sub>max</sub>* as described in 7.2):
>   `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, or
>   `unsigned long long int`.

After both operands were promoted to `int`, the result of the expression is `false` (since `0` is not less than `0`).

Then the result of this promotion is compared against `d` - here, `d` is promoted to `int` as described above, while the result of the comparison - which is of type `bool` - is promoted to `int` as well. [conv.prom]/6:

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with
>   `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

So both operands have type `int`. This second, outer comparison yields `true`, since `false`->`0` is smaller than `1`, the value of `d`.

Answer (score -1):

You code is compiled without errors, the actual error happens at linking. Most probably the linker is unable to find **32-bit versions** of runtime libraries. Have you installed them on your system?